# Disable automatic scrolling while allowing typing in cells without macros (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

I am using Excel 2016. When I type into cells at the bottom of the screen and press `Enter`, Excel moves the view down so that I can see what I just typed. Is it possible to disable this 'feature'? I am making a system where users type commands into cells (e.g you type in `foo`, then onto the cell below that you type `bar`, then `far`, then `boo`, etc.) and my view keeps moving away from the data that I want to see at the top of the page, to instead focus on the commands (which there can be hundreds of).

I've found other ways of restricting scrolling, but those all also stop users from typing in cells outside of the area (which means the commands can't be entered). I don't want anything fancy (for example, I don't mind if you can still scroll away manually); just to stop auto-scrolling.

TL;DR I want the screen to stay focused on the same table, wherever the cursor/selected cell is.

I'd preferably like to do this without macros/VB code as my system administrator is not very happy about people using them, but if it is very necessary that is fine.

Thanks.

Comment: If you use `Tab` instead of `Enter`, you will move to the next cell right, instead of down.

Comment: I know, but that doesn't change the fact that it scrolls out of the screen. TL;DR I want the screen to stay focused on the same table, wherever the cursor/selected cell is. Thanks for trying to help, though!

Comment: Moving to the right shouldn't scroll, hence the suggestion. You can always make a macro or hot-key for `Tab`+`Cursor Left` to return to the cell you have just updated.

Comment: Thanks, but it still scrolls to the right if it reaches the edge. Imagine having hundreds of commands on top of (or beside) each other - if you type another one, it will inevitably scroll. And I cannot overwrite the commands, as they are executed asynchronously on each update, so deleting them would mean that it would update improperly.

Comment: I think you can achieve it by freezing rows you want to keep visible.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/freeze-panes-to-lock-rows-and-columns-dab2ffc9-020d-4026-8121-67dd25f2508f

Comment: Great idea! Why didn't I think of this? I'll try, but maybe Excel with mess up with having to lock so much.

Comment: It works fine! If you post it as an answer, I can mark it as Answer. Perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep rows visible by freezing them.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/freeze-panes-to-lock-rows-and-columns-dab2ffc9-020d-4026-8121-67dd25f2508f